# QEmu seems to use only 1 host core for AArch64

Tags: performance, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, arm64

I am emulating AArch64 CPU on an x86_64-Ubuntu host. However, the VM is too slow. On the host I ran the System Monitor and it seems QEmu is emulating 2 AArch64 cores in one host core. `top` command in the VM shows 2 guest cores loaded to 100%. `lscpu` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` suggest that 2 cores are indeed present.

Is there a way to let QEmu use more host cores for emulation, so to make the guest faster?

I am launching QEmu with the following command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 2 -m 2048 -M virt -bios QEMU_EFI.fd -nographic \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=image \
    -drive if=none,id=image,file=xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cloud \
    -drive format=raw,if=none,id=cloud,file=cloud.img \
    -netdev user,id=user0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=user0 -redir tcp:2222::22 \
    -cpu cortex-a57
```

My another guess is that the problem could be that the CPU being emulated is too slow itself, so 1 host core is enough to emulate the 2 cores of it. This is because its BogoMIPS is only 125:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 125.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x1
CPU part    : 0xd07
CPU revision    : 0

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 125.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x1
CPU part    : 0xd07
CPU revision    : 0
```

Comment: BogoMIPS has nothing whatsoever to do with CPU speed. And [multi-threaded QEMU is not a thing yet](http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/tcg-multithread).

Comment: @Notlikethat , is there a multi-threaded alternative to QEmu for emulating AArch64 on x86_64 ?